# How to get Lotus Notes Password (on local machine) using "Interop.Domino.dll" (C#)?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am making one application where i am reading mails from Lotus Notes.
I have made this application interdependent of Domino Server.

But in this case.If user's Lotus Notes's is configured with Domino server.It shows pop-up for password.

I don't want to show pop-up.And don't want to add text box into UI.

Is there anyway to get NSF Password Programaticaly? Using Domino.dll.

Comment: It would be a serious security vulnerability if there were an API to get the password. Most secure systems (and Notes/Domino is *very* secure)  **never** store the password either on disk or in memory. They only query it from the user, verify it (usually using a cryptographic hash or something similar) and then discard it (i.e. overwrite the memory). You won't ever get the plain-text password from such a system! And that is by design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a API function to retrieve a Domino password.

There is an API function to RESET the password, but the old password is a parameter.

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't do this.  The password is not stored anywhere, but is used to gain access to the RSA private key which is what actually does the authentication.  It sounds as though you are going to the mail file on the server, though..."If user's Lotus Notes's is configured with Domino server...".  If there is a local replica of the mail file that is not encrypted you should not need to authenticate to access it.  If it is encrypted, or you need to access the server, then the user absolutely will need to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an application which runs on a client workstation, and the user has the Notes client running on that workstation, it is possible to "share" the password, so that your application does not need to prompt the user. This is an option, enabled from the Notes client. In R8, this option is under File > Security > User Security, and then under the Security Basics tab, there is a check box labeled "Don't prompt for a password from other Notes based programs."  (In R7 and earlier, its under a similar menu item, I think labeled just "User ID.")

Answer (score 0):

From the Help path: IBM Domino Designer Basic User Guide and Reference > LotusScript/COM/OLE Classes > LotusScript Classes Coding Guidelines > Accessing the Domino Objects through COM

Call session.InitializeUsingNotesUserName("name", "passwordOptional")

This is after you set session to a newly-created Lotus.NotesSession object.

(You cannot get the user password from the Domino API after it's been used to unlock the ID. You can, however, get the password from the user and then submit it to Domino through the Interop.)